# XAMPP and CURL calls error, Unsupported Browser

Tags: php, cakephp, curl, xampp

Im getting this errors on my program while trying to use the CRUL calls for a specific CURL call. This is what it returns:

```
    Array ( 
    [url] => https://mysite.myshopify.com/admin/unsupported_browser 
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=utf-8 
    [http_code] => 403 
    [header_size] => 6635 
    [request_size] => 1326 
    [filetime] => -1 
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0 
    [redirect_count] => 2 
    [total_time] => 0.812 
    [namelookup_time] => 0 
    [connect_time] => 0 
    [pretransfer_time] => 0 
    [size_upload] => 0 
    [size_download] => 0 
    [speed_download] => 0 
    [speed_upload] => 0 
    [download_content_length] => -1 
    [upload_content_length] => -1 
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.187 
    [redirect_time] => 0.625 
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => (PRIMARYIP_IS_HERE) 
    [certinfo] => Array ( ) 
    [primary_port] => 443 
    [local_ip] => (LOCALIP_IS_HERE) 
    [local_port] => 52876 
    )
```

This error only occurs on my newly installed XAMPP v3.2.2. This same code works on my live server but not on my localhost.

Here is how I set up my virtual host for this page:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\site"
    ServerName bebe2gofacturas.com
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\site">
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</virtualHost>
```

Any ideas what might be the error behind this. Im almost sure it has something to do with the XAMPP Configurations, not with the code.

EDIT:

Its worth noting that CURL calls on another plugin I have in the code does work, but the plugin for that specific CURL call is not working. Here is the properties of the plugin:

```
const _LOGIN_URL = 'auth/login';
    const _REPORT_CENTER = 'https://reportcenter.shopify.com/';

    const _COOKIE_STORE = '/tmp/shopify_cookie.txt';
    const _USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17';

    protected $ch = null,
          $ci = null;
    private $inputs = false,
        $username = false,
        $password = false,
        $store = false,
        $_token = false,
        $_dashboardToken = false;

    public function __construct($user, $pass, $store) {
        if (!preg_match('/\:\/\//', $store)) {
            $store = 'https://' . $store;
        }
        if (!filter_var($store, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
            throw new \Exception('Invalid store URL');
        }
        $this->store = $store . (substr($store, -1) == '/' ? '' : '/');
        $this->username = $user;
        $this->password = $pass;
    }
```

EDIT:
I think Its worth noticing that this same code worked on another computer I had. I know the problem must be on the set up of the Xampp, Maybe on the php.ini or the httpd.conf Somewhere along those lines.

Any ideas what i should be looking for?

I dont think its the CURL calls cause there is another plugin on this project which uses CURL calls just fine.

EDIT:

If I take out the cert.pem of the php.ini I get this next error:
[image]

D: Im not sure what to do. Any ideas are welcome hehe.

Comment: The cookie file `/tmp/shopify_cookie.txt` is not valid on Windows.  And it shows the URL as `/admin/unsupported_browser` perhaps because cookies are not functioning.  What if you fix the cookie path to be a Windows file path?

Comment: @drew010 Hey thanks for the suggestion, I tried setting up the cookie url on the Path variables, but with no luck. It still returns the same answer. I think Its worth noticing that this same code worked on another computer I had. I know the problem must be on the set up of the Xampp, Maybe on the php.ini or the httpd.conf Somewhere along those lines. Any ideas what i should be looking for?

Comment: @RyanVincent Is that really necessary? I do have a copy of this project on a live server and it is working fine there. It does recognize the Cookie_Store variable.

Comment: Most likely not related to `httpd.conf` settings.  Perhaps the cURL request is missing some headers they require?  Try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('php://output', 'w'));` and see if any helpful information is output to the browser.

Comment: @drew010 I get this next error D: 'Warning (2): curl_setopt(): cannot represent a stream of type Output as a STDIO FILE* [APP\Controller\SamplesController.php, line 373]' Im not sure I understand this error. his come from the second line of code you suggested me.